# Mac terminal cd to folder IN current directory

Tags: macos

Let say my current directory in terminal is `~/Users/Desktop`. On my desktop, there's a folder called `"sample_dir"`. How can I cd in this `"sample_dir"` folder with typing: `"cd ~/Users/Desktop/sample_dir"`? There's gotta be a shorter way that looks at your current directory and appends that path to the directory you pass in to make things faster.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is. Type:

```
cd sample_dir
```

It checks for you. If for some strange reason that doesn't work, type:

```
cd ./sample_dir
```

Answer (score 7):

I usually type **`cd`**, then drag the folder (from Finder) that I want to open in Terminal, and drop it in Terminal. This will add the full directory path, then press enter to change to the dropped directory.

Answer (score 7):

The path you are using `cd ~/Users/Desktop/sample_dir` is wrong.

If you have a folder named `sample_dir` in you user's `Desktop` directory then the full path to the directory is:

```
cd /Users/YourUserName/Desktop/sample_dir
```

Where `YourUserName` is the the short account username. Using the tilde ~ shortcut to your home directory this can be shortened to

```
cd ~/Desktop/sample_dir
```

When you open a new terminal session you start in your home directory, so:

```
cd Desktop/sample_dir
```

Answer (score 2):

Typing cd sample_dir should work... check "pwd" to make sure the current path is what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Found an even easier way with MacOS Ventura 13.0.1.

- open Finder and navigate to the folder you want to `cd` to
- ensure you can see the Path Bar (Finder > View > Show Path Bar)
- right click the folder you want to `cd` to in the Path Bar
- select 'Open in Terminal'

Et Voilà!

Comment: This does not answer the original question which is about navigating to a certain directory when someone is already in Terminal.

Answer (score -3):

cd Desktop/sample_dir

should work :)

Answer (score -3):

Dude you should do a simple step if you are using mac type cd and then use space and then drag the file you wants to open in terminal(most probably for git hub purpose).

Comment: This has already been provided as an answer https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/34325/237